# not in clause not working in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables project and department I want to get the project owner from project table who are not in department head field in department table 
I have the code

```
select p.* from project p inner join department d on p.department_string_id=d.department_string_id WHERE p.project_owner NOT IN d.department_head
```

but shows syntax error in my query.What I did wrong.Why 'NOT IN' clause is not working.

Comment: What is `d.department_head`? If it's just a single value, then you want `!=`. If it's a comma-separated list then you're doing databases *horribly* wrong (but `FIND_IN_SET()` might save you). If there are multiple rows, you may want `NOT EXISTS` instead of a `JOIN`...

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it? It would make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Are you talking about the [`expr NOT IN (value, ...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in) construct?

Answer (score 1):

`NOT IN` will work when you want to check multiple values (with comma separated in `()`). For matching single record you can use `!=` or `<>`

```
select p.* from project p inner join department d on 
p.department_string_id=d.department_string_id WHERE p.project_owner != 
d.department_head
```

Answer (score 1):

`NOT IN` is used to check if a variable is present in a collection of values (ex: `p.project_owner NOT IN (1,2,3,..)` or `NOT IN (SELECT d.department_head FROM department d)`)

In this case, you should use `!=` instead of `NOT IN` because you are checking values one by one.

```
select p.* 
from project p 
inner join department d on p.department_string_id = d.department_string_id 
WHERE p.project_owner != d.department_head
```

Answer (score 0):

using this query i think you will achieve what you want

```
select p.* from project p 
left join department d on 
p.department_string_id=d.department_string_id 
WHERE p.project_owner is null
```

btw `in` or `not in` is not used in this way. it gets values from collection.

Comment: sorry and thank you. Mistakenly I have written "in" instead of "is".Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The `NOT IN` test against a set of element not just a single one `NOT IN (foo, bar, ..)`. Depending on what you want to achieve there are two solutions to your problem:

1. If you need to test against one value, you can use the `<>` or `!=`
   operator to exclude a single value.
2. If you want **to exclude the whole** `department_head` list you can use another query to fetch the list `NOT IN (select field_name form table)`. like this:

`select p.* from project p inner join department d on p.department_string_id=d.department_string_id
WHERE p.project_owner NOT IN (select d.department_head from department d)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
select p.* from project p 
    left join department d on 
    p.department_string_id=d.department_string_id 
    WHERE d.department_head is null or d.department_head<>p.project_owner
```